# Find table row index based on value

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a list of names in column 1 and i'm looking to find the row index if the table contains a certain value.

What I've tried:

```
var nameToSearch = "Bob";
var index = $("#table-names tr").index(nameToSearch);
console.log(index);
```

But I just keep getting the same result "-1" indicating the value was not found. Although I know the value is in there. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Can you post the HTML for your table?

Comment: You should pass an element to the jQuery `.index()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var nameToSearch = "Bob";
var elem = $("#table-names tr:contains("+ nameToSearch +")");
var index = elem.index('#table-names tr');
console.log(index);
```

Comment: perfect, many thanks. 7 minutes to accept the answer, will do it as soon as i can.

Comment: no need to pass a selector. the default is to index it in relation to its siblings..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#table-names tr:contains("+nameToSearch+")").index();
```

or a bit more safe

```
$("#table-names tr")
        .filter(function(){
             return $(this).text().indexOf(nameToSearch) > -1;
        }).index();
```